# How to parse German currency numbers properly?

Tags: java, currency

I'm trying to parse german currency numbers. But what's wrong with the following test?

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("100,00");
```

Result:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "100,00"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:350)
```

Comment: Don't you need the '€' symbol in the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to parse the number without using currency use:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("100,00");
```

If you use `getCurrencyInstance` you have to also supply the € symbol:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("100,00 €");
```

Comment: April 2023, Java 17: The first example (`getInstance`) works; but the second example (`getCurrencyInstance`) throws a parse exception. The reason is due to that space between the amount and the currency symbol - it is now expected to be a non-breaking space: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("100,00\u00A0€");`.